# Paypal - show cart discount above tax

Tags: c#, paypal, shopping-cart

I've set up a 3rd party shopping cart and everything is working correctly on my site and on PayPal except for one small issue. I'm applying a discount to the entire shopping cart, and applying tax to that discounted amount. In PayPal the numbers are all correct but it's showing the discounted tax amount above the discount. Is there any way get the discount to show above the tax in PayPal. This is what it looks like in PayPal now:

```
item 1        $10.00 USD
item 2        $20.00 USD

Item total    $30.00 USD
Tax            $0.90 USD
Discount      $15.00 USD

Total         $19.40 USD
```

It "looks" like the tax (6% in this case) is being applied before the discount. I'd just like to be able to move that discount line up to be above the tax line. Is this possible? Here's my form code that passes the information to PayPal.

```
<form class="paypalform"
      action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/bn/cgi-bin/webscr"
      method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="dummy-facilitator@dummysite.com">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_@count" value="@item.ProductName">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_@count" value="@item.Price">
        count++;
        cartTotal += @item.Price;
    }
    <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount_cart" value="@ViewBag.DiscountAmount" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_cart" value="@ViewBag.TaxAmount" />
    <input type="image"
           src="http://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif"
           name="submit"
           alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

PayPal use below variables to control discount in the payment button.

discount_amount
   discount_amount2
   discount_rate
   discount_rate2
   discount_num

You can go to the link below and search the above key words for the details.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/button-manager/integration-guide/ButtonManagerHTMLVariables/?mark=html

For more details about 3rd party shopping cart issue, you can refer to the link below.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/cart_upload/